# cakephp resize component / helper

Tags: image, cakephp, components, resize

We want to resize image(s) using cakephp component available, do you know the best one, which gives us options to rezie / crop / resize n crop, kindly let me know.

thanks !

Comment: Do you mean crop and resize before upload or when displaying?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case you mean crop/resize when displaying the image. You can store the originals and either use PHPThumb or Tim thumb to resize the image on the fly when displaying them. While this doesn't allow you the option of personalized cropping, it's very flexible since any file size can be accommodated

Tim thumb : http://code.google.com/p/timthumb/